# IE7 not capturing jQuery click on child selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code which runs correctly and as expected on FF, Chrome, IE8/9 and Safari...but I cannot capture the click of 'searchSubmit' on IE7.

The [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) states that child selectors are fully supported on IE7, but I am unable to use them in this way. Is there an issue with relative positioning?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#r_submit > #searchSubmit').click(function() {
       console.log('captured click of searchSubmit');
    });
});
```

My HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="r_submit">
   <a id="searchSubmit">Go</a>
</div>

#r_submit #searchSubmit {
    background: url("/images/picco/proceed_button.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    height: 38px;
    width: 195px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You're not even using the child selector in your CSS. I see the descendant selector.

Comment: I am using `position: relative` in my CSS. See above.

Comment: There's no good reason to use a selector with two IDs. Just use `$('#searchSubmit')`

Comment: Is your js inside of the `$(document).ready` callback?

Comment: @Thomas Removing the parent selector from the click call makes no difference. Nothing is written to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only valid to have one element with a given ID on a page, so your selector could be:

```
$('#searchSubmit').click(function() {
    console.log('captured click of searchSubmit');
});
```

If the content is being dynamically added to the page, the "on" method will handle this:

```
$('#r_submit').on('click', '#searchSubmit', function() {
    console.log('captured click of searchSubmit');
});
```

Comment: The `on` won't handle dynamically created elements the way you're using it.  You have to use delegation.

Comment: You are 100% correct, thanks. I had another `#searchSubmit` on the page, although it was in another area of the page and I thought my child selector would solve this issue, it was obviously a problem for IE7. To fix this I updated the call to use `on` instead of `click` and changed the name of the div. Thankfully IE7 has only 4% worldwide usage now.